# Mongo DB cursor issue how can I return the results of a collection while omitting the input parameter (Say, User user)?

Tags: java, mongodb

This is the code I have but is not working.

```
public List<User> getAllButOne(final User user) {
    List<User> results = null;
    this.users.dropIndex(user.getUserId());
    DBCursor cursor = this.users.find()
    results = getUsersFromCursor(cursor, USER_ID_KEY);
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Can you add more explanation to your post ? Why are dropping index by user id ?

Comment: drop index first and then retrieve again from the collection with one user ommited

Comment: Why are dropping index ? Index has their own names.  It is not tied to user id. Do you mean to drop the user document from collection ?

Comment: yes i want to "hide" that user from the result I am trying to display with a http get request

Comment: Can you add the code for `getUsersFromCursor` method ? What is the problem that you are running into with the current  code ? You can use `$ne` in your query to get rest of the results.

Comment: static List<User> getUsersFromCursor(DBCursor cursor, String fieldKey){
        try{
            List<User> u = new ArrayList<User>();
            while(cursor.hasNext()) {
                u.add(new User((String)cursor.next().get(fieldKey)));
            }
            return u;
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }